# GPFlow: 'NaturalGradient' object has no attribute '_name'

Tags: python, tensorflow, attributes, gaussian-process, gpflow

I was trying to replicate the [Heteroskedastic Likelihood and Multi-Latent GP](https://gpflow.github.io/GPflow/2.7.1/notebooks/advanced/heteroskedastic.html) example from the GPFlow library site. Everything ran fine except for the last snippet of code under "Run Optimization Loop" and is throwing an error: `AttributeError: 'NaturalGradient' object has no attribute '_name'`.

> Question: Is there something I can do to fix this?

#### Code to run

```py
# [1] Import packages
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

import gpflow as gpf

# [2]: Generate data to be modeled
N = 1001

np.random.seed(0)
tf.random.set_seed(0)

# Build inputs X
X = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, N)[:, None]  # X must be of shape [N, 1]

# Deterministic functions in place of latent ones
f1 = np.sin
f2 = np.cos

# Use transform = exp to ensure positive-only scale values
transform = np.exp

# Compute loc and scale as functions of input X
loc = f1(X)
scale = transform(f2(X))

# Sample outputs Y from Gaussian Likelihood
Y = np.random.normal(loc, scale)


# [3]: Plot the data generated above to see what they look like
def plot_distribution(X, Y, loc, scale):
    plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
    x = X.squeeze()
    for k in (1, 2):
        lb = (loc - k * scale).squeeze()
        ub = (loc + k * scale).squeeze()
        plt.fill_between(x, lb, ub, color="silver", alpha=1 - 0.05 * k ** 3)
    plt.plot(x, lb, color="silver")
    plt.plot(x, ub, color="silver")
    plt.plot(X, loc, color="black")
    plt.scatter(X, Y, color="gray", alpha=0.8)
    plt.show()
    plt.close()


#plot_distribution(X, Y, loc, scale)

# [4]: Set up the likelihood function for the model we want
likelihood = gpf.likelihoods.HeteroskedasticTFPConditional(
    distribution_class=tfp.distributions.Normal,  # Gaussian Likelihood
    scale_transform=tfp.bijectors.Exp(),  # Exponential Transform
)

print(f"Likelihood's expected latent_dim: {likelihood.latent_dim}")

# [5]: Specify the kernels of the mean and variance GPs
kernel = gpf.kernels.SeparateIndependent(
    [
        gpf.kernels.SquaredExponential(),  # This is k1, the kernel of f1
        gpf.kernels.SquaredExponential(),  # this is k2, the kernel of f2
    ]
)

# [6]: We will use the SVGP model which requires inducing points
M = 20  # Number of inducing variables for each f_i

# Initial inducing points position Z
Z = np.linspace(X.min(), X.max(), M)[:, None]  # Z must be of shape [M, 1]

inducing_variable = gpf.inducing_variables.SeparateIndependentInducingVariables(
    [
        gpf.inducing_variables.InducingPoints(Z),  # This is U1 = f1(Z1)
        gpf.inducing_variables.InducingPoints(Z),  # This is U2 = f2(Z2)
    ]
)

# [7]: Build the SVGP model using the components instantiated above
model = gpf.models.SVGP(
    kernel=kernel,
    likelihood=likelihood,
    inducing_variable=inducing_variable,
    num_latent_gps=likelihood.latent_dim,
)

model

# [8]: Build optimizers (NatGrad + Adam)
data = (X, Y)
loss_fn = model.training_loss_closure(data)

gpf.utilities.set_trainable(model.q_mu, False)
gpf.utilities.set_trainable(model.q_sqrt, False)

variational_vars = [(model.q_mu, model.q_sqrt)]
natgrad_opt = gpf.optimizers.NaturalGradient(gamma=0.1)

adam_vars = model.trainable_variables
adam_opt = tf.optimizers.Adam(0.01)


@tf.function
def optimisation_step():
    natgrad_opt.minimize(loss_fn, variational_vars)
    adam_opt.minimize(loss_fn, adam_vars)


# [9]: Run optimization loop
epochs = 100
log_freq = 20

for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
    optimisation_step()

    # For every 'log_freq' epochs, print the epoch and plot the predictions against the data
    if epoch % log_freq == 0 and epoch > 0:
        print(f"Epoch {epoch} - Loss: {loss_fn().numpy() : .4f}")
        Ymean, Yvar = model.predict_y(X)
        Ymean = Ymean.numpy().squeeze()
        Ystd = tf.sqrt(Yvar).numpy().squeeze()
        plot_distribution(X, Y, Ymean, Ystd)

model
```

#### versions of packages

```
print(tf.__version__) --> 2.11.0
print(tfp.__version__) --> 0.19.0
print(gf.__version__) --> 2.7.1
```

#### More Details

More of the error message is as follows:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-aee9c220de71> in <module>
      3 
      4 for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
----> 5     optimisation_step()
```

...and continues

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/gpflow/optimizers/natgrad.py in tf___natgrad_steps(self, loss_fn, parameters)
     21                     loss = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(loss_fn), (), None, fscope)
     22                 (q_mu_grads, q_sqrt_grads) = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tape).gradient, (ag__.ld(loss), [ag__.ld(q_mu_vars), ag__.ld(q_sqrt_vars)]), None, fscope)
---> 23                 with ag__.ld(tf).name_scope(f'{ag__.ld(self)._name}/natural_gradient_steps'):
     24 
     25                     def get_state():

AttributeError: in user code:

    File "<ipython-input-10-2722f09bae9a>", line 16, in optimisation_step  *
        natgrad_opt.minimize(loss_fn, variational_vars)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/check_shapes/integration/tf.py", line 208, in wrapped_method  *
        return wrapped_function(self, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/check_shapes/decorator.py", line 120, in wrapped_function  *
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/gpflow/optimizers/natgrad.py", line 236, in minimize  *
        self._natgrad_steps(loss_fn, parameters)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/check_shapes/integration/tf.py", line 208, in wrapped_method  *
        return wrapped_function(self, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/check_shapes/decorator.py", line 120, in wrapped_function  *
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/gpflow/optimizers/natgrad.py", line 266, in _natgrad_steps  *
        with tf.name_scope(f"{self._name}/natural_gradient_steps"):

    AttributeError: 'NaturalGradient' object has no attribute '_name'
```

I tried changing Tensorflow to an older version which did not work. I also tried looking at GPFlow source code for [NaturalGradient](https://gpflow.github.io/GPflow/2.7.1/_modules/gpflow/optimizers/natgrad.html#NaturalGradient) but I'm afraid this didn't help me come to a solution.

Comment: Hi, without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (that is, include code for creating the data, setting up `model`, defining `optimisation_step` etc.), it is hard to reproduce what your issue is. However, this might be a bug in the code, so it might be more helpful to [open it as an issue](https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/issues/new?assignees=&labels=bug&template=bugs-performance-issues.md) on GPflow.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue but I found a workaround. You can just set the name for now using something like:

```
natgrad_opt._name = 'natgrad-opt'
```

It's not pretty but it seems to do the job. The constructor also takes a name parameter but it does not seem to store it to the right attribute (self.name not self._name).